# Create a branch in an empty repository using the Java API for Bitbucket

Tags: java, git, api, rest, bitbucket

I have created an empty repository using the java library for bitbucket. But when trying to create a branch, the error "my-repo" is empty - branches cannot be created in empty repositories. Tell me how to add data to the repository via the API. I have used `com.cdancy library`.

**Code:**

```
CreateRepository crepo = CreateRepository.create("my-repo", true); 
Repository repo = client.api().repositoryApi().create("ESB", crepo); 
CreateBranch master = CreateBranch.create("branchname", "hashcommit", null); 
Branch mast = client.api().branchApi().create("Proj", "my-repo", branch);
```

**Maven dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cdancy</groupId>
    <artifactId>bitbucket-rest</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: are you trying to create the branch or adding the data?

Comment: To create a branch, I need to add data to the repository, please tell me how can I add it using java?

Comment: from where you are adding the data

Comment: The idea is that Jira, using a java plugin, creates a repository and a master branch when creating a development task. Any commit should be made to an empty repository by Jira.